# xpath to scrape data from javascript google maps markers, using chrome scraper

Tags: javascript, xpath, web-scraping, google-maps-markers, screen-scraping

I'm trying to learn how to scrape data that's embedded inside of a javascript google maps marker.

Here's an example of the kind of code that I want to scrape from, not the actual intended code. Note: let me repeat, this is just an example, not the actual intended page.

I put the code in a paste-bin because the code snippet is so huge:
http://pastebin.com/sVZq4B5j

From this code, I want to extract data such as:

> "centroid_id":"23913",
>
> "latitude":"35.899757906753",
>
> "longitude":"-79.046030044556",
>
> "location_name":"UNC McColl Building",
>
> Contact Info
>
> James Britton
>
> UNC McColl Building
>
> Availability: Generally Mon, Tues, and Wed afternoons are available.
>   Please email me if you would like to request a time. I am not
>   available on the weekends.
>
> Parking: After 4 pm there is no parking fee.  If during the day, there
>   is a parking meter in the visitor lot which charges about $1.50 per
>   hour.
>
> Fee: $25.00
>
> Fee details:$25 for 2hr exam and $35 for 3hr exam. Fee is for location
>   and proctoring
>
> Computer based exams: Yes
>
> Online/Internet based Exams: Yes
>
> Quiet environment for computer based exams:Close and constant
>   supervision for computer based exams: Yes
>
> Paper based exams: Yes
>
> Quiet environment for paper based exams: Yes
>
> Close and constant supervision for paper based exams: Yes
>
> ADA accessible: Yes

What's the XPath expression to do this? I'm using the Scraper Chrome Extension. Is there any other way I can do this?

Also, can anyone explain what the strings of /t , /n , \t and \n are for? E.g.:

```
\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\n\n\t\t<\/td>\n\n\t<\/tr>\n\n\t\t\n\n\t\n\t<tr>\n\n\t\t\t
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is not XPath, but a way to parse the code and get you the parts that you need. 
One way could be using regular expressions, which doesn't work well on html, another way could be using HTML parsers.

Anyways you need some programming skills to use any of those. For example with some node/javascript skills you can use [this](https://github.com/tautologistics/node-htmlparser) parser to get the job done.

Quoting from the docs of node-htmlparser, this html:

```
<a href="test.html">xxx</a>
```

becomes:

```
[ { type: 'tag'
  , name: 'a'
  , attribs: { href: 'test.html' }
  , children: [ { data: 'xxx', type: 'text' } ]
  }
]
```

So basically you can read any text contents and pour them into JavaScript variables.

And about the last part of your question: 
\n is the newline character
\t translates into a tab

Comment: Could you descrube more the parser features?